# Lightning input percent - 0% not displaying

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a inputNumber with a percent. If I fill with a number its ok, but I fill with 0, the field show only the icon %. I want to show or **0%** or **nothing**.

```
<ui:inputNumber class="slds-input columns" value="{!v.familysObj.contingenciaPorcent}" change="{!c.changeValue}" format="##%"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the format as `#0%`, this works similar to `apex:param` in visualforce:

```
<ui:inputNumber class="slds-input columns" value="{!v.familysObj.contingenciaPorcent}" 
    change="{!c.changeValue}" format="#0%"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works correctly